# detecting a hard drive in the IDE

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to detect the drive letter in Windows. Drive is a primary drive in second IDE channel. I am using `GetLogicalDrives()`.

But this does not tell me I am accessing IDE primary drive.

Comment: The drive letter has nothing to do with whether it's on the primary channel or not. You can reassign drive letters with the Disk Manager to any values you want. What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am creating a file in this drive. I need to know this drive path to create a directory. there is no user interaction with the application.

Comment: Is it the drive letter of the drive holding the Windows installation, or the drive letter specifically associated with the master drive in the second IDE channel?

Comment: But you still haven't explained what the primary/secondary channels have to do with anything. Are you looking for *the disk that Windows is on* (which does not have to be on the primary channel)? Are you looking for the disk that the computer booted from? As I asked before, **what specifically are you trying to do**?

Comment: Wow, I haven't thought about primary/secondary IDE channels for 10 years. There's this thing now called SATA...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

const char* GetTypeOfDrive(const char* Drive)
{
    const char* Result = NULL;
    unsigned int DriveType = GetDriveType(Drive);

    switch(DriveType)
    {
        case DRIVE_FIXED:
            Result = "Hard disk";
            break;

        case DRIVE_CDROM:
            Result = "CD/DVD";
            break;

        case DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
            Result = "Removable";
            break;

        case DRIVE_REMOTE:
            Result = "Network";
            break;

        default:
            Result = "Unknown";
            break;
    }

    return Result;
}

int GetLogicalDrivesList(char Drives[26])
{
    int Res = 0;
    DWORD DrivesMask = GetLogicalDrives();

    for (int I = 0; I < 26; ++I)
    {
        if (DrivesMask & (1 << I))
        {
            Drives[Res++] = 'A' + I;
        }
    }
    return Res;
}

int main()
{
    char temp[4];
    char drives[26];

    int drive_count = GetLogicalDrivesList(drives);

    for (int i = 0; i < drive_count; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(temp, "%c:/", drives[i]);
        printf("%c is a %s\n", drives[i], GetTypeOfDrive(temp));
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide any information about whether or not the disk is on the primary or secondary IDE channel, which is what the poster seems to be asking about (at least according to the subject).

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't realise what he was asking. I couldn't solve it anyway. I tried this: http://pastebin.com/XmSp0wj8  but no cigar on my computer. I'm not sure that there is a way without writing a driver (maybe).